# Formalization of abstract definitions

Tags: type-theory, dependent-type

I'm asking about the `abstract` keyword in Agda and equivalent features in other languages. It marks a definition as non-expandable, potentially speeding up typchecking later.

On first glance this seems to be a great threat to subject reduction and other properties. Is this feature treated formally (at least in a toy language) anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know about any formal description of `abstract` in the literature. However, the top-level `abstract`-s are very easy to model: convert `let abstract x : A = t in u` to `(λ (x : A). u) t`. For `abstract` in local scope, we can do the same, but we don't get the Agda behavior. To get that, we first do a lambda-lifting of the abstract local definition to the top, and then do the desugaring to lambda abstraction. For example:

```
let f : A → B → C
  = (λ a b. let abstract g : C = exp1 in g)
in exp2
```

is translated to

```
(λ (g : A → B → C).
 let f : A → B → C = (λ a b. g a b)
 in exp2)
(λ a b. exp1)
```

Answer (score 5):

Maybe if you look at things the other way around, you’ll see why this is not a particularly deep feature from the type-theoretic point of view. Instead of viewing an abstracted definition as a definition that is later hidden, you can view it as an axiom that is later inhabited. We surely know how to work with an axiom in a context! It of course breaks canonicity, but otherwise all (and in particular subject reduction) is well.

Regarding `abstract`ed proofs specifically, though, the work on strict propositions gives a nice "type-theoretic" approach, in particular one that preserves canonicity.

Currently in Coq, proofs (ie terms `p` such that `p : P : Prop`) are made as opaque as possible (more or less the equivalent of `abstract` in the Agda world). However, in some cases where informative content depends on it, it is still authorized to be reduced. Think for instance of having `p : nat = nat`, and `0` transported along `p`. This will reduce to `0` only if `p` is convertible to `refl`. This is needed if one wants canonicity to hold.

The idea with strict propositions is that whenever `p : P : SProp` and `q : P : SProp`, `p` and `q` are convertible. This implies that a proof of a strict proposition `P` never ever needs to be looked at during conversion/evaluation, because its value is irrelevant, since it is convertible to all other inhabitants of that type. Thus, any such proof behaves as if it were `abstract`ed, but without losing any equational content you would have if it were transparent. In particular, you can have `abstract`ed propositions that are never expanded, but still retain canonicity.

I guess the current best reference on this is Pujet and Tabareau’s *Observational Equality: Now for Good*, if you want to read more. There’s some implementation in Coq, but it is still quite experimental.